# Arms of the night

Tags: rebus, visual

This puzzle attempts to portray a specific scene in a well known movie from the 1970's.  The meaning of the symbols is important although the specific symbol may or may not be part of the movie.

The objective is to name the scene and the movie.

[image: ArmsOfTheNight]

Comment: I knew the solution as soon as I saw the word "branches".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Potential answer:

> The Black Knight scene from Monty Python and the Holy Grail

Symbolism for sides of picture:

> The scene takes place at a bridge over a small stream. King Arthur comes out of the forest on the left, the black knight is guarding the bridge on the right

Central part of image (with the cross):

> King Arthur is a knight on a mission given to him by god - seeking the holy grail

Underneath left (3 crowns):

> On the left we have King Arthur, who has arms and has 3 crowns - for... something. I'm not sure about this part. My best guess is that he has three crowns - the one on his head and the two coconut halves that his squire is banging together to simulate a horse.

Underneath right (w/o arms):

> On the right we have the black knight ("night") whose arms have been chopped off by King Arthur.

Source (if you haven't seen the movie, go see it right now):

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eMkth8FWno

Comment: Won't lie - I didn't think that was actually it! Was I right about the "crowns"?

Comment: Hmm. I guess night w/o arms was a giveaway. King Arthur's coat of ARMS was 3 crowns on an azure background but that was not in the movie.  Above is the green knight with "cross" ARMS meaning dead...